# Clone of Static Class

Tags: c#, reflection, static, activator

I am using static list to keep some string values, when application starts  just one static list is enough, but after a while i need to keep different strings in different static lists, is there any way to deep copy or clone of a static class with different name at the runtime in C#

```
public class Foo
{
    public static List<string> orders;
}
```

as you can see above, I can add and remove  static Foo.orders easily, but in runtime  i need another class for example Foo2 class. By the way, list must be static, however i need to reach list from different classes, also a cannot create new classes while developing, because how many static list I do not know

thank you

Comment: This is exactly what object instances are for. "cannot create new classes while developing". I think you are missing something important. I think a better question might be, "how do I pass instances of objects around in my code" or something similar.

Comment: If you need to add something in run time, then it isn't static.

Comment: What do you mean by "in runtime i need another class for example Foo2 class"  Do you mean you want a _second_ `Foo` class, or are you literally creating a class at runtime using code generation?

Comment: Are you just using a `static` class out of convenience? If you need to perform any type of runtime operations, then you probably need to be passing things around as opposed to using the same (and only) static instance of an object.

Comment: i don't think so it is possible

Comment: If you need different lists, then it should not really be declared as static. You're misusing OO principles here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create new static classes at run-time, but you can keep a static dictionary of lists:

```
public class Foo
{
     public static Dictionary<string,List<string>> Lists 
                                                      = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>
     {
         {"orders", new List<string>()}
     };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely must be using a `static` class to handle this and you are expecting to be manipulating it after it is instantiated (e.g. creating other lists, etc.) then you might consider creating another element that could handle that behavior such as a `List<List<string>>` or a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` :

```
public static Dictionary<string,List<string>> Orders = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

If you were to use a dictionary, then you could store a key for each of your available lists (i.e. `List1`, `List2` and then access each list by using its key) :

```
Foo.Orders["List1"]; // yields your first list
```

and

```
Foo.Orders.Add("List2",new List<string>()); // Create a new list in your Dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really must have the convenience of referencing the list without an instance being passed around, you'll want to move away from a static class (which is global by definition) and into the realm of Singletons which are stored in whatever scope you prefer (cached for the thread or execution path, for example).

However, I'd seriously consider rethinking your approach, as passing instances might be more appropriate from the sound of it.

Answer (score -3):

Best practice is to create a separate public static field for every possible list you could ever need. I would write a script to generate the code for at least 10,000 lists.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static List<string> orders1;
    public static List<string> orders2;
    public static List<string> orders3;
    public static List<string> orders4;
    public static List<string> orders5;
    public static List<string> orders6;
    public static List<string> orders7;
    public static List<string> orders8;
    public static List<string> orders9;
    public static List<string> orders10;
    public static List<string> orders11;
    public static List<string> orders123;
    public static List<string> orders13;
    public static List<string> orders14;
    public static List<string> orders15;
    public static List<string> orders16;
    public static List<string> orders17;
    public static List<string> orders18;
    public static List<string> orders19;
    public static List<string> orders20;
    public static List<string> orders21;
    public static List<string> orders22;
    public static List<string> orders23;
    public static List<string> orders24;
    public static List<string> orders25;
    public static List<string> orders26;
    public static List<string> orders27;
    public static List<string> orders28;
    public static List<string> orders29;
    public static List<string> orders30;
    public static List<string> orders31;
    public static List<string> orders32;
    public static List<string> orders33;
    public static List<string> orders34;
    public static List<string> orders35;
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely insane.

Comment: please don't waste comment space, people need it to make real comments